# Build a JPQL on a BLOB with Spring Data JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql, querydsl

Im working with an external service which POSTs to an endpoint in my application where i have a `@RequestBody CalloutRequest calloutRequest` where i map the request body to the Class `CalloutRequest`.

As part of that CalloutRequest is a field called `userAttributes` which looks like this in my class:

```
@Lob    
private HashMap<String, List<String>> userAttributes;
```

I have it annotated wit `@Lob` because i have no class that i can map it to due to it's rather complex nature. Therefore this HashMap. An example of what userAttributes looks like this when in JSON format:

```
  "userAttributes": {
    "lastName": [
      "Guy"
    ],
    "ExternalId": [
      "d9a59407-2bca-46aa-8641-3350fd95bcd1"
    ],
    "distinguishedName": [
      "CN=t2-contractor9,DC=company,DC=com"
    ],
    "employeeID": [],
    "userName": [
      "t2-contractor9@company.com"
    ],
    "groupNames": [
      "ALL USERS",
      "T2-Contractor@company.com"
    ],
    "firstName": [
      "T2-Contractor"
    ],
    "UserStore": [],
    "phone": [],
    "domain": [
      "company.com"
    ],
    "disabled": [
      "false"
    ],
    "email": [
      "t2-contractor9@company.com"
    ]
  }
```

My challenge is that i would like to build a query for a particular username - `userAttributes.userName` - but given the fact that this is stored as a BLOB i cannot figure out how - or if at all possible - to write such a query.
Right now i am simply using Spring Data JPA and it's repository implementation but im wondering if this is something i can achieve with a custom `@Query` or perhaps using querydsl?

Am i correct in understanding that if i could figure out a way to map the above HashMap into an actual class i could use to serialise/de-serialise and have a mapping between a CalloutRequest and this new class i could build a JPQL query that would use a join to achieve what i am after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about leveraging an `AttributeConverter` implementation here:

```
public class YourEntity {
  // ...
  @ElementCollection
  @Convert(name = "value", converter = StringListToStringConverter.class)
  private Map<String, List<String>> userAttributes;
}
```

A simple implementation of `StringListToStringConverter` might be:

```
public class StringListToStringConverter 
       implements AttributeConverter<List<String>, String> {
    private static final String DELIMITER = "|";

    @Override
    public String converToDatabaseColumn(List<String> attributes) {
      if ( attributes == null || attributes.isEmpty() ) {
        return null;
      }

      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      for ( Iterator<String> i = attribtues.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        sb.append( i.next() );
        if ( i.hasNext() ) {
          sb.append( DELIMITER );
        }
      }
      return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override 
    public List<String> convertToEntityAttribute(String data) {
      if ( data == null ) {
        return new ArrayList<String>();
      }

      List<String> values = Arrays.asList( StringHelper.split( DELIMITER, data ) );         
      return new ArrayList<String>( values );
    }
}
```

You would obviously have to handle situations where the input stream contained your `DELIMITER` value of sorts, but it might work depending on your use case.

I believe you can then use HQL to write your query like:

```
SELECT e FROM YourEntity e JOIN e.userAttributes a 
WHERE VALUE(a) = :mapValue
```

Comment: That seems to work really well! I am able to implement the entity with the `@ElementCollection` and `@Convert`.

However i am unable to get the query to work most likely because i dont fully understand what the `StringListToStringConverter ` actually does.
I thought i could just pass a String for i.e. username into the query method but that fails with "Parameter value did not match expected type [java.util.List]" - what exactly do i need to provide so that the converter can understand my method?

Comment: I apologize I did not test this, so perhaps you may need to tweak the query as `WHERE VALUE(a) IN (:mapValues)` and supply the named parameter as a `List<String>`?

Comment: That gives me a:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List` from the `convertToDatabaseColumn` method.

My `@Query` annotated method looks like this in my repository:

`CalloutRequest findWhereUser(@Param("userName") List<String> userName);`

Comment: I was unable to get a HQL or JPQL query to function but with a `@Query` method like the below which has nativeQuery enabled i can make a regular JOIN work:

`@Query(nativeQuery = true, value =
            "SELECT * FROM CALLOUT_REQUEST AS C JOIN CALLOUT_REQUEST_USER_ATTRIBUTES AS A ON C.ID = A.CALLOUT_REQUEST_ID WHERE A.USER_ATTRIBUTES = :userName ORDER BY C.ID")
        List<CalloutRequest> findWhereUser(@Param("userName") String userName);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hibernate as JPA implementation and PostgreSQL as DB take a look to [hibernate-native-json](https://github.com/velo/hibernate-native-json) project:

**Example**

You can serialize either a class or a Map (in any cases a more dynamic field is necessary).

```
@Entity
public class MyClass {

  @Type(type = "com.marvinformatics.hibernate.json.JsonListUserType")
  @Target(Label.class)
  private List<Label> labels = new ArrayList<Label>();

  @Type(type = "com.marvinformatics.hibernate.json.JsonUserType")
  private Map<String, String> extra;

}
```

This allow a HQL query like this:

```
select
    json_text(i.label, 'value')
from
    Item i
where
    json_text(i.label, 'lang') = :lang
```

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately i am using H2 file based DB (small project) but i will definitely remember this for future projects! Thanks.